# Change text and styling of a form control when a slider value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form

Having a hard time to achieve what I'm looking for. I was thinking of using arrays but don't know where to start. Code below is what I want to shorten to get rid of multiple `if` statement using jQuery.

```
$("input#communication").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    if(slideEvt.value == 1) {
        $('#slider-val1').css('color', '#D0011B');
        $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val1').css('color', '#ccc');
        $('.slider-handle').css({
            'border': '5px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #D0011B'
         })
        $("#desc").text('Amir is a terrible communicator.');
    }

    if(slideEvt.value == 2) {
        $('#slider-val2').css('color', '#D0011B');
        $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val2').css('color', '#ccc');
        $("#desc").text('Amir struggles, needs a lot of help to improve communication skills.');
    }

    if(slideEvt.value == 3) {
        $('.slider-handle').css({
            'border': '5px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #D0011B'
        })
        $('.slider-handle').css('background', '#D0011B');
        $('.slider-selection').css('background', '#D0011B');
        $('#slider-val3').css('color', '#D0011B');
        $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val3').css('color', '#ccc');
        $("#desc").text('Amir needs some help to improve communication skills.');
    }

    if(slideEvt.value == 4) {
        $('.slider-handle').css('background', '#F47621');
        $('.slider-selection').css('background', '#F47621');
        $('#slider-val4').css('color', '#F47621');
        $('.slider-handle').css({
            'border': '5px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #F47621'
        })
        $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val4').css('color', '#ccc');
        $("#desc").text('Amir has below average communication skills.');
    }

    if(slideEvt.value == 5) {
        $('#slider-val5').css('color', '#F47621');
        $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val5').css('color', '#ccc');
        $("#desc").text('Amir has adequate communications skills.');
    }
});
```

The code above use to change the `$('#desc')` text and CSS every time the slider is slide. Now, I'm looking for a good way on how to shorten this`if else` statements.

Comment: Can you change/update your CSS and HTML as well or only the JavaScript? Could you add the HTML or at least the example of one slide to the question?

Comment: A good solution probably involves rewriting more than just the JavaScript. Could you show us the corresponding HTML as well, ideally with a live demo? (When [edit]ing the question, press Ctrl-M.)

Answer (score 2):

You are duplicating a lot of code here. You said you wanted an array, so make an array containing all the values that change and then use the `slideEvt.value` to recall the values from the array at the correct index..

Something like this maybe.. no `if()` statements required (at least not for the `slideEvt.value`):

```
$("input#communication").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    var slideEvtVals = [
      {color: '#D0011B', css: {'border': '5px solid #fff', 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #D0011B'}, text: 'Amir is a terrible communicator.'}
      {color: '#D0011B', text: 'Amir struggles, needs a lot of help to improve communication skills.'}
      {color: '#D0011B', css: {'border': '5px solid #fff', 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #D0011B'}, text: 'Amir needs some help to improve communication skills.', handleBG: '#D0011B', selBg: '#D0011B'}
      {color: '#F47621', css: {'border': '5px solid #fff', 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px #F47621'}, text: 'Amir has below average communication skills.', handleBG: '#F47621', selBg: '#F47621'}
      {color: '#F47621', text: 'Amir has adequate communications skills.'}
    ];

    var index = slideEvt.value-1;
    $('#slider-val'+slideEvt.value).css('color', slideEvtVals[index].color);
    $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val'+slideEvt.value).css('color', '#ccc');
    if(slideEvtVals[index].css) $('.slider-handle').css(slideEvtVals[index].css);
    $("#desc").text(slideEvtVals[index].text);
    $("#desc").text(slideEvtVals[index].text);
    if(slideEvtVals[index].handleBG) $('.slider-handle').css('background', slideEvtVals[index].handleBG);
    if(slideEvtVals[index].selBg) $('.slider-selection').css('background', slideEvtVals[index].selBg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple improvement is to use `else if` instead of multiple `if`s.

Taking out common statements in the each of `if` statement.

1. `$('#some-selector').css('color', '#some-color');`
2. `$('.slider-label').not('#some-selector').css('color', '#ccc');`
3. `$('#desc').text('Some Message');`

By making the *some...* part dynamic, we can make this code common for all conditions.

For the message, we can use either object or array(in case of numeric keys) and store the message on that key.

The colors `color`, `background` & `box-shadow` can also made dynamic using below condition.

```
var color = value <= 3 ? '#d0011b' : '#f47621';
```

Now, the statements using these colors are dynamic and can be moved outside of their respective `if` statements.

After making all the common things dynamic, there need to add special conditions for case 1, 3 & 4.

---

Below is compete code with description comments:

```
// Array starts at zero'th index
var description = [undefined,
    'Amir is a terrible communicator.',
    'Amir struggles, needs a lot of help to improve communication skills.',
    'Amir needs some help to improve communication skills.',
    'Amir has below average communication skills.',
    'Amir has adequate communications skills.'
];

$("input#communication").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    // Get the value and convert to number
    var value = Number(slideEvt.value);
    // Dynamic color based on value
    var color = value <= 3 ? '#d0011b' : '#f47621';

    // Dynamic selectors based on value
    $('#slider-val' + value).css('color', color);
    $('.slider-label').not('#slider-val' + value).css('color', '#ccc');

    // Special handling for some values
    if (value === 1 || value === 3 || value === 4) {
        $('.slider-handle').css({
            'border': '5px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0 0 0 2px ' + color
        });


        // Only for 3 & 4
        if (value === 3 || value === 4) {
            // Multiple selectors
            $('.slider-handle, .slider-selection').css('background', color);
        }
    }

    // Get message at that index
    $('#desc').text(description[value]);
});
```

I'll suggest to move the styles in CSS classes and add/remove the classes using JavaScript.

If ES6 is supported in the target environment, you can take advantage of its features like [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a `switch` statement to replace all the `if`s, and extract the parts that are the same except for the selector (like the CSS), and use a variable to create a string to pass to the selector. Instead of `$('#slider-val5')` use `document.getElementById('slider-val' + slideEvt.value)`.

Comment: `switch` will also be long. I was thinking about making an array but thanks though.